# Galaxy S5とAndroid 5.1.1でdo/whileが正しく機能しない

Tags: android, java

何の変哲もないコードなのですが、Galaxy S5およびAndroid 5.1.1の組合せの場合
のみ、do/while文が不可解な動きをします。原因をご存知の方はいらっしゃらない
でしょうか？

```
int i = 0;
int j = 0;

do {
    Log.d(TAG, "[test do-while 1] i = " + i + ", j = " + j);
    i = 0;
    Log.d(TAG, "[test do-while 2] i = " + i + ", j = " + j);
    i++;
    Log.d(TAG, "[test do-while 3] i = " + i + ", j = " + j);
    i++;
    Log.d(TAG, "[test do-while 4] i = " + i + ", j = " + j);
    j++;
    Log.d(TAG, "[test do-while 5] i = " + i + ", j = " + j);
} while (j < 5);
```

Galaxy S5 (Android 5.1.1)で出力したログは以下の通りです。

```
D/MainActivity( 9856): [test do-while 1] i = 2, j = 0
D/MainActivity( 9856): [test do-while 2] i = 2, j = 0
D/MainActivity( 9856): [test do-while 3] i = 2, j = 0
D/MainActivity( 9856): [test do-while 4] i = 2, j = 0
D/MainActivity( 9856): [test do-while 5] i = 2, j = 1
D/MainActivity( 9856): [test do-while 1] i = 2, j = 1
D/MainActivity( 9856): [test do-while 2] i = 2, j = 1
D/MainActivity( 9856): [test do-while 3] i = 2, j = 1
D/MainActivity( 9856): [test do-while 4] i = 2, j = 1
D/MainActivity( 9856): [test do-while 5] i = 2, j = 2
D/MainActivity( 9856): [test do-while 1] i = 2, j = 2
D/MainActivity( 9856): [test do-while 2] i = 2, j = 2
D/MainActivity( 9856): [test do-while 3] i = 2, j = 2
D/MainActivity( 9856): [test do-while 4] i = 2, j = 2
D/MainActivity( 9856): [test do-while 5] i = 2, j = 3
D/MainActivity( 9856): [test do-while 1] i = 2, j = 3
D/MainActivity( 9856): [test do-while 2] i = 2, j = 3
D/MainActivity( 9856): [test do-while 3] i = 2, j = 3
D/MainActivity( 9856): [test do-while 4] i = 2, j = 3
D/MainActivity( 9856): [test do-while 5] i = 2, j = 4
D/MainActivity( 9856): [test do-while 1] i = 2, j = 4
D/MainActivity( 9856): [test do-while 2] i = 2, j = 4
D/MainActivity( 9856): [test do-while 3] i = 2, j = 4
D/MainActivity( 9856): [test do-while 4] i = 2, j = 4
D/MainActivity( 9856): [test do-while 5] i = 2, j = 5
```

それ以外の組合せで試すと以下の通り想定通りの動きをします。

```
D/MainActivity( 9515): [test do-while 1] i = 0, j = 0
D/MainActivity( 9515): [test do-while 2] i = 0, j = 0
D/MainActivity( 9515): [test do-while 3] i = 1, j = 0
D/MainActivity( 9515): [test do-while 4] i = 2, j = 0
D/MainActivity( 9515): [test do-while 5] i = 2, j = 1
D/MainActivity( 9515): [test do-while 1] i = 2, j = 1
D/MainActivity( 9515): [test do-while 2] i = 0, j = 1
D/MainActivity( 9515): [test do-while 3] i = 1, j = 1
D/MainActivity( 9515): [test do-while 4] i = 2, j = 1
D/MainActivity( 9515): [test do-while 5] i = 2, j = 2
D/MainActivity( 9515): [test do-while 1] i = 2, j = 2
D/MainActivity( 9515): [test do-while 2] i = 0, j = 2
D/MainActivity( 9515): [test do-while 3] i = 1, j = 2
D/MainActivity( 9515): [test do-while 4] i = 2, j = 2
D/MainActivity( 9515): [test do-while 5] i = 2, j = 3
D/MainActivity( 9515): [test do-while 1] i = 2, j = 3
D/MainActivity( 9515): [test do-while 2] i = 0, j = 3
D/MainActivity( 9515): [test do-while 3] i = 1, j = 3
D/MainActivity( 9515): [test do-while 4] i = 2, j = 3
D/MainActivity( 9515): [test do-while 5] i = 2, j = 4
D/MainActivity( 9515): [test do-while 1] i = 2, j = 4
D/MainActivity( 9515): [test do-while 2] i = 0, j = 4
D/MainActivity( 9515): [test do-while 3] i = 1, j = 4
D/MainActivity( 9515): [test do-while 4] i = 2, j = 4
D/MainActivity( 9515): [test do-while 5] i = 2, j = 5
```

その他確認した事実は以下の通りです。

・while文やfor文に書き換えると問題は発生しない。
・logを疑って自作ログに置き換えても事象は変わらない。
・Galaxy S4およびS6では発生しない、Anroid 5.0.2でも発生しない。

Comment: 回答に対する返答らしきものが回答として投稿されていたので、コメントに変換しました。本来質問者は回答にコメントできるのですが、質問時と異なるアカウントを使われたように見えます。必要であればアカウントのマージも可能です。（参考 http://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts ）

Answer (score 2):

何らかの最適化が行われているという可能性はないでしょうか？

例えば、*Log.d()* はアプリのリリース時に、取り除かれたと仮定すると、

```
int i = 0;
int j = 0;

do {
    i = 0;
    i++;
    i++;
    j++;
} while (j < 5);
```

実質的にこのような形であり、最適化によって、*i = 0;* から *i++;* への 3 行が、*i = 2* とまとめられてしまうことが考えられます。

```
int i = 0;
int j = 0;

do {
    i = 2;
    j++;
} while (j < 5);
```

その上で、改めて、*Log.d()* を再配置したような結果となっているように思われます。

もし、この推測（最適化の影響であるということ）が正しければ、最適化を妨げるような形にすれば、結果が違うはずです。

```
int i = 0;
int j = 0;
int k = 0;

do {
    Log.d(TAG, "[test do-while 1] i = " + i + ", j = " + j);
    i = 0;
    Log.d(TAG, "[test do-while 2] i = " + i + ", j = " + j);
    i++;
    k += i;
    Log.d(TAG, "[test do-while 3] i = " + i + ", j = " + j);
    i++;
    k += i;
    Log.d(TAG, "[test do-while 4] i = " + i + ", j = " + j);
    j++;
    Log.d(TAG, "[test do-while 5] i = " + i + ", j = " + j);
} while (j < 5);

Log.d(TAG, "k = " + k);
```

たとえば、このようにすることによって、*k* の演算が間に割り込むことによって、*i* に関する 3 行を *i = 2* とまとめて最適化するわけにはいかなくなるので、期待していた通りの結果になるのではないでしょうか？

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。
はい、最適化は怪しいです。ご指摘の対応を入れると回避可能です。 再現ソースはログ出力のみですが、実際はメソッド呼び出しを行っていて
意図していない値がメソッド側に渡されていることが問題です。 最適化が影響していることを切り分けできるようなビルド設定などをご存知ないでしょうか？

Comment: コンパイラ/JIT最適化の影響を切り分けたいならば、[android:vmSafeMode](https://androidbycode.wordpress.com/2015/07/03/disable-android-art-ahead-of-time-compilation-to-optimize-debug-deployment/)が役立つ可能性があります。（未検証ですが）